# How can login to a website such as Stock X using python request (request module)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, basic-authentication

I'm having trouble finding which link I have to enact the POST request to along with what necessary credentials and or headers.

I tried

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

callback = 'https://accounts.stockx.com/login/callback'
login = 'https://accounts.stockx.com/login'
shoe = "https://stockx.com/nike-dunk-high-prm-dark-russet"
headers = {
    
    }
request = requests.get(shoe, headers=headers)
#print(request.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())```

but I keep getting 

`Access to this page has been denied`
````

Comment: Maybe they are just blocking you, because it's against their terms of use? And BTW, your code never uses the `login` variable. And maybe you shouldn't use an empty header. Perhaps you can also try to understand how HTTP works and what headers actually are, before you are coding by coincidence

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting a very difficult task as a lot of these websites have impeccable bot detection.

You can try mimicking your browsers headers by copying them from your browsers network request menu (CTRL-SHIFT-i > then go to the network tab). The most important being your user-agent, then add it to your headers. They will look something like this:

```
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"}
```

However you'll probably be met with some sort of captcha or other issues. It's a very uphill battle my friend. You will want to look into understanding http requests better. Look into proxies and not being IP limited. But even then, these websites have much more advanced methods of detecting a python script / bots such as [TLS Fingerprinting](https://scrapfly.io/blog/how-to-avoid-web-scraping-blocking-tls/) and various other sorts of fingerprinting.

Your best bet would to try and find out the actual API that your target website uses if it is exposed.

Otherwise there is not much you can do except respect that what you are doing is against their Terms Of Service.